# Can I search for issues (wildcard) using the Redmine REST API?

Tags: web-services, rest, redmine

I know you can query for issues using known values (i.e. project_id=1), but is it possible to query for issue via wildcard search (i.e. issue_subject=*wildcard*, or issue_description=*wildcard*)? The [REST API](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_Issues) documentation doesn't seem to indicate that, but I'm hopeful someone else has been able to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't appear to be part of the API. You'd have to extend redmine yourself.

Luckily, it seems someone has already done it for you:

http://www.redmine.org/issues/6277